# What are the effective home based pesticides?

Tags: pest-control

Sometimes my plants gets infected by different insects, unless I notice it, it gets very late to save the plant.

Chemical based insecticide works well, but I am fearful while using\spraying and storing it, as they are very poisonous.

So, I am looking for the home based solution which should be effective and safe.

It will be ok for me if home based solution take some more time to heal the plant as compared to chemical based pesticide.

Comment: *added **nettle** to my post*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most common 'household' remedy used on plants is a squirt of washing up liquid in a spray full of water to treat for aphid infestation. Neem oil is another thing which many people use, but you have to bear something in mind on this subject. Everything on the planet is made of chemicals, including you - it is only the combination and quantity of chemicals which matters. Neem oil in its neat state is dangerous if misused or consumed, and you'd have to store that somewhere - the same applies to household bleach and other cleaners you might commonly use.

There is an ongoing argument regarding the use of such things as washing up liquid in water as a treatment in that it's no less dangerous to the environment than many of the made-for-purpose aphid treatments you can buy off the shelf. My personal choice is to only use treatments when it's absolutely essential, to buy the right product for the right job rather than one which treats for lots of other problems which aren't present currently, to use sparingly, and store the remainder carefully in a safe place in the original container. You might, though, want to investigate neem oil in particular, bearing in mind that you will need to store the container somewhere safe.

Comment: You just cleared away my disbelieves..! I will check about neem oil..! Thank you Sir..!

Comment: Erm, that should be madam, not sir, though titles are not my thing!

Comment: Once again, you have cleared away my misbelieve..! :) Thank you Mam!

Answer (score 2):

***Little things at hand***

**Garlic** - For large plants (cherry, apricot, peach, etc. ..) - **Insects, aphids, ants** -

A natural way, not harmful to the environment, effective and invigorating to plants to which it is addressed, and especially suitable for removing insects from diseased plants. Personally, I tried it on a cherry tree and within two weeks parasites are gone.

It is enough to bury around the plant to be treated, spaced about 40 cm from the trunk, a dozen cloves of garlic sprouts, soon to be themselves seedlings. The roots of the infested plant will absorb the mood of garlic and this will begin to flow in the lymph of the same, resulting in a short time, a disinfectant, all insects away naturally. Garlic is also a natural antibiotic, for bacterian deseases.

**Tobacco** - For every plants indoor also -

Soak in the water a few cigarette butts, smoked, for at least one night, after which it is filtered everything and you put obtained water in a spray. We can then go spraying of diseased leaves with this water, preferably in the morning, and let it carries on its activities throughout the day. In the evening it is better to rinse the leaves with clean water, to avoid the effect of tobacco burned damaged in some way the plant. Within a few days the effects should be visible.

Another method similar is to macerate for a night and the quantity of tobacco of three cigarettes in half a liter of water with the addition of three garlic cloves squeezed. The next day everything is filtered and poured into a sprayer that you're going to wet the leaves of plants attacked by aphids or other insects. In this case serves no rinse, since the compound obtained is not harmful to the plant.

**Lemon** - For every plant, large or small, indoor or outdoor, environnement and lawn - (in particular **ants**)

Cut one or more lemons in half. Let them do their green mold. Place the half rotten lemons on the base of plants and paths of the ants. Renew them when too old.

**Nettle** - For every plant - **Aphyds** -

Decoction of nettles. You put abundant doses of nettle leaves in cold water, boil and when it comes to a boil turn off and allow to cool. Then you drain and use treated water on the plants.

All those methods I use normally and find a very good result.

Comment: Thanks! Will try these! I had used Lemon on Ants earlier, it worked..!

Comment: Remember that rot lemons smell very bad. So i suggest you don't put them in your dining room :)

Comment: Find a cigar smoker and get some butts from them for making tobacco water. It's higher in nicotine (the active ingredient) and there is more material in each butt. Never heard the rotten lemon one...